# How do I convert this to Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My T SQL -
left(convert(char,Month,111),7) "Year-Mon"

Below is the error I'm getting
Error: invalid identifier 'CHAR'

Comment: Can you provide samples of the data that you are converting from and to?  That would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
to_char(to_date(Month,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'yyyy-mm') "Year-Mon"
```

From your question, I assumed,
`Month` is a string in yyyy/mm/dd format.
And you are expecting a string in yyyy-mm format.